# Parse expressions on custom interpreter

Tags: java, interpreters

I'm currently developing my own (sort of) programming language.
It currently looks something like this:

```
asdf = 2;
print(asdf);
```

And

```
print(2);
```

And surprisingly, it works. (Both output `2`)
However, the problem is I can't do this:

```
print(sqrt(25));
```

I also can't do this:

```
asdf = sqrt(25);
print(asdf);
```

My big problem is I can't use functions in of arguments and variable declarations.
How would I implement this?
(I will give code for the interpreter if needed)

Comment: Can you provide more information?  "I can't" doesn't really tell us the problem you're having.  Is it that you don't know how?  Or that it isn't working as intended?

Comment: Eventually, you're going to need a general purpose expression parser, I think.  Things to handle: constants, variables, parenthesis, unary/binary/prefix/postfix operators, operator precedence & associativity,  function invocations, array indexing, casts, syntax errors, etc.  I would consider a strategy that tackles these things head-on, and all together, rather than adding one at a time more as an afterthought.  You might consider a parser generator, like [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org); there are others, as well.  (Or, you could learn how to write a parser from scratch.)

Comment: Alright, I'll try that.
Also, I've googled and can't find a tutorial for creating parsers. Anyone got one?

Comment: An [example of ANTLR](https://ivanyu.me/blog/2014/09/13/creating-a-simple-parser-with-antlr/) implementation. It shows how to deal with basic operators (numericals and logicals) but it's a good example to start with

Comment: @Midnightas - if you really want to do this right, [this book](http://www.amazon.com/Compilers-Principles-Techniques-Tools-2nd/dp/0321486811) is what you're looking for. It's a bit pricey, though, so it may be best to find a library with a copy...

Comment: @Midnightas: Writing a parser from scratch isn't the easiest thing to grok - most people learn the concepts through classes and textbooks. Your best bet is to first write a lexer (tag every token in your input program as a type of symbol) and then read up on recursive descent parsing (the simplest type of parsing). This should more than give you the background you need to write something more advanced than this.

Answer (score 1):

You have to evaluate the inner function first, take its result and feed it into your outer function.

In most interpreters, this is typically done by pushing the outer function (and its parentheses) onto a stack.  You then evaluate the inner function, obtain the answer, pop the outer function, hand it the answer from the inner function, and evaluate the outer function.

Answer (score 0):

> `asdf = sqrt(25);`

This part is one of the most useful, as you can rewrite majority of code as assignments of function results to variables.
For example:

```
print(sqrt(25));
```

can be rewritten as:

```
tmp0 = sqrt(25);
print(tmp0);
```

Using this method you can easily handle even nested calls:

```
print(sqrt(pow(5, 2));
```

is rewritten as:

```
tmp0 = pow(5, 2);
tmp1 = sqrt(pow0);
print(tmp1);
```

and so on.

I don't know how you implemented you interpreter, but one of the simplest approaches is to first tokenize your input (i.e. turn a source text into a sequence of lexemes - basic symbols that represent different parts of your language's grammar) and then traverse that sequence.
Remember that you can perform several passes over the sequence of lexemes, in each pass producing gradually simpler sequences until you have something you can easily work with.

Example:

```
print(sqrt(25));
```

may be tokenized into the following sequence:

```
"print"
"("
"sqrt"
"("
"25"
")"
")"
";"
```

When traversing the sequence you look for patterns (e.g. `identifier "("`) and take actions when you find a match.
For example, matching `identifier "("` triggers a nested call in you interpreter to rewrite the sequence if the analyser finds nested calls.
Then, you will rewrite it to a modified sequence that may look like this:

```
"tmp0"
"="
"sqrt"
"("
"25"
")"
";"
"print"
"("
"tmp0"
")"
";"
```

To make rewriting easier you can operate on two sequences: a raw input sequence, and a fresh one for rewritten program.
Using this method you rewrite and rewrite until you arrive at something simple enough to execute.
That's, from a very high level, is basically what happens with most programming languages.

I'd advise you to read up on programming language design, lexers, parsers, and source code analysis.
I'd also suggest you try to write a simple DSL before starting a much more complex task of implementing a general purpose language.
Learning more than one programming language also helps when you want to design your own.

Comment: Yes, I did use the token approach. Thank you for your answer.
I'm just not sure how to handle the for-loop messing up (the one that's reading the tokens).

Comment: What do you mean by "for-loop messing up"?

Comment: Never mind. I fixed that problem.